# Meta CV tag - [statistics] vs [site-statistics]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-excerpt, tag-wiki, meta

A recent suggested edit to the [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics) tag wiki (and excerpt) came up.

The change was to make it explicitly for discussion of statistics relating to activity on the main site (things like my recent question relating to answers per question).

I think having a tag for such a purpose is an excellent idea.  As such I (though with some uncertainty) approved the suggested edit. I am still unsure about it, hence this post.

So to my questions:

- Is there a need for a [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics) tag in the more usual sense?
- If that is the case, might a [site-statistics](/questions/tagged/site-statistics) tag be better for the purpose of discussion relating to statistics about the main site?

---

[This is now finalized - the [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics) tag was renamed [site-statistics](/questions/tagged/site-statistics) via a tag-merge.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have manually retagged 2 Qs with [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics) tag and 1 additional Q with [probability](/questions/tagged/probability) into [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic).

The remaining 8 threads with [statistics](/questions/tagged/statistics) are all about site statistics, so it can now be renamed into [site-statistics](/questions/tagged/site-statistics) via moderator tools. I suggest you can do it now!

The wiki excerpt says

> Questions about sizes and other quantities of Cross Validated Stack Exchange site. E.g. number of unanswered questions, response/question rate, GB/day transferred, etc.

which looks fine.

Comment: I merged into the new tag name. Thanks very much for this.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a great idea, and we could make `[statistics]` a synonym.  If there's some confusion about which site is referenced, you could use `[main-sites-statistics]` instead.

Comment: +1, but maybe using "site" in singular form?[main-site-statistics]

Comment: @AndreSilva, that was meant to be the possessive case, not plural, but you're right: it may be better without the "s".

Comment: FYI: This has just been implemented by Glen_b.